# Script RDP Server Port change

Tags: powershell

i am very new and only amateur. only thing i did before with script is creating terminal server.
My company have a problem. RDP connection and the antimalware service blocking bruteforce attacks and almost every server gets notifications from inbound connections blocked; svchost.exe blocks from unknown IP's etc.
Very new for me.

after reading a hour trough solutions i think changing port 3389 for RDP is the fastest and resolve 90% of the problem.  (445,5985 getting inbound blocks from antivirus too "svchost.exe")

I already use VPN on every server. Next thing i want to ask is a script or even connect it here where i only need to put allowed IP inside the code.

```
Write-host "NEWPORT " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
$RDPPort = Read-Host
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-TCP\" -Name PortNumber -Value $RDPPort
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "NewRDPPort-TCP-In-$RDPPort" -Direction Inbound –LocalPort $RDPPort -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "NewRDPPort-UDP-In-$RDPPort" -Direction Inbound –LocalPort $RDPPort -Protocol UDP -Action Allow
Restart-Service termservice -force
Write-host "NEWPORT " -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

Is the code correct and i dont kill every server or programs cant run normal anymore? Thank you for any response!

I did change port manual, brute force attacks stopped for the server. Then i allowed inbound connection for new random port and

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to change the RDP port (but ive not tested it) - however this is a classic example of "security by obscurity" - its an improvement but not really a solution.

Yes this approach will reduce the number of connection attempts as there are lots of scripts/scrapers/scanners out there that are only looking for default ports, but its not hard to perform a port scan and locate your RDP port if its still exposed to the internet so this wont solve the problem entirely.

A better solution is to restrict what IPs can attempt an RDP connection in the first place - though this becomes more complicated and is dependent on your skills and available resources to implement (and theres a risk of locking yourself out of your servers!). You mention VPN but dont describe its setup - its certainly possible to route RDP traffic over a VPN and avoid exposing it to the internet which would be a better solution. Another common solution is to use a "jump host" - a linux box that you make an SSH connection and port forward your RDP connections through. Your windows servers then only need to allow the jumphost access to RDP and not the internet in general.

Also be aware Windows could have numerous other ports open like RPC and SMB which are also exploitable and run on known ports (i would suggest your conduct a port scan of your server yourself to see what is open).